# CSS: <elementType> before or after .className?

Tags: css

What is the difference between declaring:

```
p.myClass { color: red; }
```

and

```
.myClass p { color: red; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is `all p elements with class myClass`:

```
<p class="myClass"></p>
```

and the second one is `all p elements inside element has class myClass`:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! So if I have:
    <div class="myClass">
        <p>testing<p>
    <div>
p.myClass wouldn't change anything, and myClass.p would style the "testing", yes?

Answer (score 1):

the first means `p` has a class `.myClass` the second one means all the `p`  which  `.myClass` is the parent/ancestor will have the rules you apply

```css
p.myClass {
  color: red
}

.myClass p {
  background: red;
  margin: 10px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="myClass">
  <p class="someClass">this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
  <p>this will be red</p>
</div>
<hr />
<p class="myClass">this will be red</p>
<hr />
<section class="myClass">
  <div class="someClass">
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
    <p>this will be red</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: would change _parent_ to _ancestor_ to be specific

Comment: ya changed that

Answer (score 1):

`p.myClass` refers to elements with p tag having .myClass

`p .myClass` refers to elements with elements having class inside element with p tag

`.myClass p` refers to elements with p tag inside element having class 'myClass'

Answer (score 0):

`p.myClass` is referring to a paragraph elements with a class of "myClass":

```
<p class="myClass">
```

`.myClass p` refers to the a paragraph element which is a descendant (child) of any element with a class of "myClass". For example:

```
<div class="myClass">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

The space used here is called a CSS "combinator", which is a relationship operator between multiple selectors. You can read about combinators here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

Additionally, you can read more about CSS selectors here:  https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: I had looked at that page, but it doesn't actually show the results of "element.class" or ".class element". Going to the ".class" link also doesn't show an example of or explain the difference in regards to ".class element".

Comment: Sorry about that. I've updated my answer with a page that explains the usage of spaces in CSS selectors. It's called a "combinator" and defines a relationship between two selectors.

Answer (score -1):

p.className will assign the CSS rules to the

designated elements only.

```css
.testClass
{
 color:red;
}

p.testClass
{
 color:blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Template</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Template.css">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script src="Template.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <main>
  <div class=testClass>
   This text should be red.
  </div>
  
  <p class=testClass>
   This text should be blue. 
  </p>
  
  
 </main>
 
 <footer>
 Copyright &copy; 2017~M.A.F.
 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```